# Dual DAC channel selection in PIC

Tags: pic, spi, dac

I need to communicate with this DUAL DAC by using SPI : [MAX 5223 Dual DAC](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5223.pdf)

There are 2 DAC outputs in this chip and I am confused that how can I select and write to the specific one. There is CS pin with this explanation in datasheet:

> CS: Chip Select. Active-Low. Enables data to be shifted into the 16-bit shift register. Programming commands
>   are executed at the rising edge of CS

I believe this is for selecting this chip not related to choosing output. So I have these 2 questions:

1. How can I write to OutA or OutB? If I transmit data with SPI, how will I choose which output source that will be active?
2. Since this one is DAC, I will need to send fractions like 1.5, 2.3 etc. There is no command in datasheet for it, so how can I send values like I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write a command to the chip which tells which DAC you want to update. Read datasheet page 8. You can't send fractions, you send integers between 0 and 255 as it is an 8-bit DAC, and the output voltage is between 0 and reference.

Comment: I missed that part, thanks!